# Powershell: Union list of hashtable - taking the latest one on collision

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am currently trying to union a list of N hashtables - where each of the tables contains a timestamp together with another list of hashtables.

The idea is to union the list of hashtables and take on collision the one row coming from the table with the highest timestamp.

As an example:

```
@(
    @{
       week = '2020-05'
       participants = @(
           @{
               name = 'user A'
               age = 35
               address = 'city A'
           },
           @{
               name = 'user B'
               age = 16
               address = 'city B'
           }
       )
    },@{
       week = '2020-04'
       participants = @(
           @{
               name = 'user A'
               age = 35
               address = 'city A'
           },
           @{
               name = 'user B'
               age = 16
               address = 'city A'
           },
           @{
               name = 'user C'
               age = 42
               address = 'city B'
           }
       )
    }
)
```

Note that for interpretation, on 2020-05, we received 2 users, while on 2020-04 we received 3.

Now, the final goal is to get a list like this:

```
result = @(
    @{
        week = '2020-05'
        name = 'user A'
        age = 35
        address = 'city A'
    },
    @{
        week = '2020-05'
        name = 'user B'
        age = 16
        address = 'city B'
    },
    @{
        week = '2020-04'
        name = 'user C'
        age = 42
        address = 'city B'
    }
)
```

My question is now: Is it possible to solve this without having to have an explicit loop - but with an foreach or select object? I already was able to get an array of unique user names using select object / distinct - but here I am interested not only in a list of possible names - but together with the combination of name / age and address.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this here, since it has code and thus too long for a comment section.

But... but, 'user b' is in both weeks, but different addresses. In normal thought, those are two different folks, because their residence is in two different locations. So, your final result, that you are after, if that is the case, is not valid.

```
Clear-Host

@(
    @{
       week = '2020-05'
       participants = @(
           @{
               name = 'user A'
               age = 35
               address = 'city A'
           },
           @{
               name = 'user B'
               age = 16
               address = 'city B'
           }
       )
    },@{
       week = '2020-04'
       participants = @(
           @{
               name = 'user A'
               age = 35
               address = 'city A'
           },
           @{
               name = 'user B'
               age = 16
               address = 'city A'
           },
           @{
               name = 'user C'
               age = 42
               address = 'city B'
           }
       )
    }
) | 
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty SyncRoot | 
Select Week -ExpandProperty participants

# Results
<#
name   age address week   
----   --- ------- ----   
user A  35 city A  2020-05
user B  16 city B  2020-05
user A  35 city A  2020-04
user B  16 city A  2020-04
user C  42 city B  2020-04
#>
```

Using Select -Unique

```
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty SyncRoot | 
Select Week -ExpandProperty participants | 
Select -Unique Name, age, address

# Results
<#
name   age address
----   --- -------
user A  35 city A 
user B  16 city B 
user B  16 city A 
user C  42 city B
#>
```

Of course, dropping the city will give you the three you are after, well, I am just showing name and age here. If the username can't absolutely be assured of being unique, then, well, you know.

```
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty SyncRoot | 
Select Week -ExpandProperty participants | 
Select -Unique Name, age

# Results
<#
name   age
----   ---
user A  35
user B  16
user C  42
#>
```

Now getting the address and the week back into the listing before converting back to a has table, is another matter, since that would not be available in that final Select statement.

Lastly, what is your reason(s) for not using a loop, if that gets you your needed results? As from my experiments thus far, it'd a much simpler thing to do, vs what I've tried thus far and what I've posted here.

***Update***

Ok, I think I've got this for you not. Really not sure why it did not come to me in my initial post, especially when using Group-Object gave me my first clue.

```
# Convert JSON and use Sort unique to work with data
Clear-Host
$HasheTableExport | 
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty SyncRoot | 
Select Week -ExpandProperty participants | 
Sort-Object -Property name -Unique

<#
# Results

name   age address week   
----   --- ------- ----   
user A  35 city A  2020-05
user B  16 city B  2020-05
user C  42 city B  2020-04
#>

# View as JSON
Clear-Host
$HasheTableExport | 
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty SyncRoot | 
Select Week -ExpandProperty participants | 
Sort-Object -Property name -Unique | 
ConvertTo-Json

# Results
<#
[
    {
        "name":  "user A",
        "age":  35,
        "address":  "city A",
        "week":  "2020-05"
    },
    {
        "name":  "user B",
        "age":  16,
        "address":  "city B",
        "week":  "2020-05"
    },
    {
        "name":  "user C",
        "age":  42,
        "address":  "city B",
        "week":  "2020-04"
    }
]
#>
```

Then leverage/convert as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. To give you a quick background: I asked for the alternative solution because I assumed it might be more efficient since this can utilize the built-in functions of Powershell. Regarding the name: Try to think of this as the PK of the data we receive on a daily basis - and changing addresses just implies, that there was an update from one week to the next. In the result, we want to have a list of all users across all weeks - with the most up to date data we have for them

Comment: But thank you for your reply - this already helped a lot - now I only need to find out how to retrieve the latest row should there be a duplicate on the name

Comment: No worries. I am still looking at it, because of the general interest of the use case and to see if I can solve it completely. If you do, before anyone else does, be sure to update for all to benefit from it.